# Can a web service on server interact with the hardware of the client machine

Tags: .net, web-services, server, client, cardreader

I am developing a web service that is consumed by a client.The client interacts with the hardware(Reader) for card insertion,but the sdk for reading the card is with web service in server.Can sdk reader interact with the hardware of the client machine to detect the card and read it?I am using .Net

Comment: is the hardware pluggedin in to server or client? Most of browser doesn't allow any access to client machine.using plugins NPAPI may be possible but people are taking the support away because of security reasons. If its only windows you may try silverlight out of browser mode but silverlight support also is going down.

Comment: the hardware is pluggedin to client ,but can be read by sdk in server.

Comment: if the hardware has some kind of driver on client system and provides a web service interface may be that can help. without any details on sdk its hard to predict

Comment: Yes,it has a driver.The sdk is EIDA SDK.

Comment: looks like it uses activex so you surely need a plugin and IE. it also says java applet. those are NPAPI plugins try getting the plugin and install and give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you're after is an "agent" that will sit on clients 's machine and talk to your server. Does not matter what it's made in - ActiveX, Java, .NET - the task it has is to monitor the hardware and communicate with the server. For that you may use .NET WCF or anything else for simplicity's sake - establish a channel of communication - http, sockets etc - and start talking to the server.